# Rails Routes Wrong Prefix

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, prefix

I'm getting a strange error when renaming the resourcce "like" to "love"

In routes.rb I've changed:

```
resources :likes
resources :recipes do
  member do
    get :likes
  end
end
```

to

```
resources :loves
resources :recipes do
  member do
    get :loves
  end
end
```

and rake:routes says

```
              loves GET    /loves(.:format)                        loves#index
                    POST   /loves(.:format)                        loves#create
           new_lofe GET    /loves/new(.:format)                    loves#new
          edit_lofe GET    /loves/:id/edit(.:format)               loves#edit
               lofe GET    /loves/:id(.:format)                    loves#show
                    PATCH  /loves/:id(.:format)                    loves#update
                    PUT    /loves/:id(.:format)                    loves#update
                    DELETE /loves/:id(.:format)                    loves#destroy
       loves_recipe GET    /recipes/:id/loves(.:format)            recipes#loves
            recipes GET    /recipes(.:format)                      recipes#index
                    POST   /recipes(.:format)                      recipes#create
         new_recipe GET    /recipes/new(.:format)                  recipes#new
        edit_recipe GET    /recipes/:id/edit(.:format)             recipes#edit
             recipe GET    /recipes/:id(.:format)                  recipes#show
                    PATCH  /recipes/:id(.:format)                  recipes#update
                    PUT    /recipes/:id(.:format)                  recipes#update
                    DELETE /recipes/:id(.:format)                  recipes#destroy
```

and ofcourse i get an error

uninitialized constant User::Lofe

but where comes the prefix "Lofe"? looks a bit strange for me

Comment: https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/2407-inflector-singularising-loves-to-lofe-but-pluralizing-love-to-loves  seems to be known / won't fix.

Comment: Show your controller code @Stef Hej

Comment: you could possibly overwrite it in `config/inflections.rb `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the active support pluralization features in rails.

To solve your issue:

in `config/initializers/inflections.rb` add the following:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.uncountable %w(Loves)
end
```

After running `$ rake:routes` I get:

```
 Prefix Verb   URI Pattern               Controller#Action
loves_index GET    /loves(.:format)          loves#index
            POST   /loves(.:format)          loves#create
  new_loves GET    /loves/new(.:format)      loves#new
 edit_loves GET    /loves/:id/edit(.:format) loves#edit
      loves GET    /loves/:id(.:format)      loves#show
            PATCH  /loves/:id(.:format)      loves#update
            PUT    /loves/:id(.:format)      loves#update
            DELETE /loves/:id(.:format)      loves#destroy
```

Comment: Also, if you want to keep track of your routes while developing, you can add this gem: https://rubygems.org/gems/restful_routing